# many "META-INF/ already added, skipping" warnings when building assembly

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

when building a jar-with-dependencies with the assembly plugin, I get many, many messages like this:

```
META-INF/ already added, skipping
```

It seems to mee, that maven is warning me, that I already have a META-INF in my to-be-created jar, and therefore the META-INF of the to-be-included dependant jar file is not included in my to-be-created jar. Well, this is exactly what I want, and I want to ged rid of those messages. Is there a way to achieve this?

Regards,
Martin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I surpress maven assembly plugin skipping files that are already added? Or allow overwrite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596655/how-do-i-surpress-maven-assembly-plugin-skipping-files-that-are-already-added-o)

Answer (score 6):

The info messages are coming from the Plexus Archiver. There is an open bug report on this issue:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLXCOMP-129

Comment: I would encourage people to vote for that JIRA item in the hopes that it will get fixed soon. (Or submit a patch!)

Answer (score 3):

The Plexus bug mentioned by vocaro has been fixed.  Using the maven-assembly-plugin with version 2.4 (highest at time of writing) does not print the verbose messages.

Comment: indeed explicitely specifying 2.4 for the plugin fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Maven won't create the META-INF twice if it has already been created but it should add the content from the various JARs to it. However, it won't add non-unique files n-times, nor merge the content.

Isn't this what you're experiencing? What does the assembly jar looks like? What is the expected result?

Comment: Hi Pascal,

thanks for your answer. The jar file's content is exactly what I'm expecting. I just want to get rid of the INFO messages that flood my console. Do you know, how to make this?

Comment: F***!
This info is kind of obsolete, because it is exactly what I would expect. So why is it printed with INFO level and not DEBUG.
Anyway, thanks for your help.